# Vue error after packaging the project Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: vue.js

[image]All js files packaged for the vue-cli2.9 version project report errors Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

The following is the error message.
I am requesting a js file but returning me an html file

Below is my Node.js code

```js
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var fs = require('fs');


var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    var html = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/index.html'), 'utf-8');
    res.send(html);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});


module.exports = app;



app.listen(8081, function () {
    console.log('Node服务启动...');
})
```

Comment: Try by adding <base href="/" /> into the <head> of your index.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but this method is not working.